# Java Servlet and JSP/JSF Help/Guidance

Tags: eclipse, jsp, jsf, tomcat, servlets

I've had very limited exposure to Java Web development side and suddenly been asked to work on a web application and learn to maintain it. I’m struggling to setup an environment to be able to test and debug existing code given to me.

I'm on windows XP. Using Eclipse and Tomcat 5.

The web app they've dumped at me has the following structure:

```
Parent_directory
    |- src
        |- mainapp
                |- model
                    |- AssignT.java
                    |- LeavePerm.java
                    |- Invoice.java
                    |- ....
                |- util
                    |- Dates.java
                    |- reports.java
                    |- .....
        |- application.properties
        |- DB.properties
        |- log.properties
        |- email.properties
        |- ......
    |- Webroot
            |-images
                |- 1.png
                |- ......
            |-jsp
                |- index.jsp
                |- email.jsp
                |- assign.jsp
                |- leave.jsp
                |- .....
            |-META-INF
                |- context.xml
                |- MAINFEST.MF
            |-Scripts
                |- display.js
                |- info.js
                |- dates.js
            |-WEB-INF
                |- classes
                    |- {EMPTY}
                |- lib
                    |- {MANY .jar files}
                |- faces.config.mex
                |- faces.config.xml
                |- web.xml
```

The web application is working but minor modifications need to be made hence why I need to be able to setup an environments with eclipse and tomcat 5 to be able to make those changes and test.

Having installed tomcat and tomcat eclipse plugin I've added the tomcat server in server tab so eclipse knows where tomcat is and able to start/stop it but cannot get it to load the above imported project and run it. Trying the "Add or Remove" option on the server tells me "there are no resources that can be added".

I would appreciate any help or guidance.

Thank you

Comment: This looks like a very typical setup. You just need to properly import the project into Eclipse and things should go smoothly after that.

Comment: can you tell me how that is done for a web application structured as above? From what you're saying the problem might be that SVN checkout isn't the proper way of importing this kind of project into eclipse? if not how else.

Comment: If I remember correctly, you may need to right click the Parent_Directory and do a Run As... -> Run on Server... to publish it to the server initially.

Comment: thanks for trying to help. I'm going to try your suggestion and let you know how it went. but just to confirm importing the project into eclipse by way of subclipse "checkout project into eclipse" is not a problem right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you download package labelled "`Eclipse for Java EE Developers`"? If so, then it contains WTP and make sure the project as the facet "Dynamic Web Module" selected.

> In eclipse Facets are used as markers for enabling user interface
>   elements.

**How to activate a Facets:**

- **Not a faceted project** then go in  **Project > Properties > Project Facets** Click on "Convert to faceted form...".
- **Already faceted project** go in  **Project > Properties > Project Facets** Select "Dynamic Web Module" with the proper version 2.3 or 2.5.

After you should be able to add the project to the tomcat server in the server tab.

More information on [Dynamic Web projects and applications](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.wst.webtools.doc.user/topics/twcreprj.html).

Comment: Thanks for your Answer, I tried what you suggested (I do have Java EE) and converted the project into faceted form" and picked Dynamic Web Module. But now all the import lines that start with javax.* are underlined red!

Comment: You need to add the Tomcat server runtime to the project build path.

Comment: @Matt Ball is right go to **Project > Properties > Java build path >** In the **Libraries** tab click **Add library..** select **Server runtime** and select the version.

Comment: Did as you said matt, Parent Directory -> Build Path -> configure Build Path -> Libraries -> Add External JARs -> Selected all the jar files in C:\tomcat5\common\lib and OK. I stil have all import javax.*..... underlined red! any suggestions?

Comment: corrected the steps to match your @Joel Hudon, javax.* import issues remain there.

Comment: did you have specific name of what class in the javax.* package is missing maybe it's jsf class or other class that are not bundled with tomcat that are missing.

Comment: how can i determine which Dynamic Web Module version i need?

Comment: The problem import lines are javax.mail.*;  javax.faces.*;

Comment: The version in Dynamic Web module is the Servlet SPEC API Version (javax.servlet.*) . The 3.0 it's for tomcat 7. Tomcat 5.5 use 2.4 but for you use 2.3 to be sure.

Comment: For the missing jar check http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/index.html and http://javaserverfaces.java.net/ you have to pick the version that fit with the code and add it to tomcat/common/lib and your class path. The easiest can be to ask at your boss or production guy to ship you the tomcat the application is already running in and you will have all the necessary jar in the common/lib folder instead of doing it one by one.

Comment: @JoëlHudon let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2874/discussion-between-techventure-and-joel-hudon)